# How to remove duplicates from tables with columns of type CLOB?

Tags: db2, clob, db2-luw

I have a table with one or more colums of type CLOB.
This table contains duplicate rows.
Normal mechanisms like `distinct` and `group by` don't work for `CLOB`s in DB2.
How can I remove the duplicates on such tables?

Answer (score 1):

One way of approaching this, especially if this is something that you will need to do regularly, is to compare CLOB *digests*, or *hashes* instead of CLOBs themselves.

DB2 does not have a built-in hash function available to you, so you'll need to jump through some hoops to accomplish that. For example, you could export CLOBs as files and calculate their hashes using an OS utility.

Alternatively, you could create a simple user-defined function written in Java (which has built-in MD5 and various SHA algorithm support). One such solution is [described in detail here](http://www.datori.org/?p=10).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to utilize the [`dbms_lob.compare`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/r0055117.html) function to compare the content of CLOB fields. It is a built-in module. The supported CLOB size is up to 10MB.

Comment: If my understanding of documentation is correct, the dbms_lob.compare function is intended to compare clobs in one table row to each other. How can this be used to eliminate duplicate rows?

Comment: You would need to write a procedure. First I would try to find rows where the CLOB has the same length and then use the compare function to see whether they match. Because LOBs are stored separately from the regular table data, going for the length first is faster. Are there any other columns that would help identifying duplicates? It is not trivial...

Comment: I have one field of type varchar which contains a guid that could be used to identify duplicates. I tried to use this in combination with the min function to select one row. But the min function doesn't also work with clobs

Comment: How long are the CLOBs? And maybe add your not working query to the question.

Comment: the clobs have a length of 1,073,741,823.